# What does this sed syntax mean? "s/MY_BASE_DIR=\(.*\)/MY_BASE_DIR=${MY_BASE_DIR-\1}/"

Tags: bash, sed

This is a simple question but i am unable to find it in tutorials. Could anybody please explain what this statement does when executed in a bash shell within a folder containing .sh scripts. I know -i does in place editing, i understand that it will run sed on all scripts within the current directory. And i know that it does some sort of substitution. But what does this `\(.*\)` mean?

```
sed -i 's/MY_BASE_DIR=\(.*\)/MY_BASE_DIR=${MY_BASE_DIR-\1}/' *.sh
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.*` matches everything after `MY_BASE_DIR=` and `\(.*\)` captures it in group #1 that back-reference is being used in replacement `\1`

Comment: For more details, [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) is the RTFM link. Note: Some features are GNU sed specific. They are marked as GNU additions in the manual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an expression like:

```
sed -i 's/XXX=\(YYY\)/XXX=ZZZ/' file
```

This looks for a string `XXX=` in a file and captures what goes after. Then, it replaces this captured content with `ZZZ`. Since there is a captured group, it is accessed with `\1`. Finally, using the `-i` flag in `sed` makes the edition to be in-place.

For the replacement, it uses the following syntax described in [Shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> **${parameter:-word}**
>
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.
>   Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

Example:

```
$ d=5
$ echo ${d-3}
5
$ echo ${a-3}
3
```

So with `${MY_BASE_DIR-SOMETHING-\1}` you are saying: print `$MY_BAS_DIR`. And if this variable is unset or null, print what is stored in `\1`.

All together, this is resetting `MY_BASE_DIR` to the value in the variable `$MY_BASE_DIR` unless this is not set; in such case, the value remains the same.

Note though that the variable won't be expanded unless you use double quotes.

---

Test:

```
$ d=5
$ cat a
d=23
blabla
$ sed "s/d=\(.*\)/d=${d-\1}/" a   # double quotes -> value is replaced
d=5
blabla
$ sed 's/d=\(.*\)/d=${d-\1}/' a   # single quotes -> variable is not expanded
d=${d-23}
blabla
```

Andd see how the value remains the same if `$d` is not set:

```
$ unset d
$ sed "s/d=\(.*\)/d=${d-\1}/" a
d=23
```

Answer (score 3):

The scripts contain lines like this:

```
MY_BASE_DIR=/usr/local
```

The sed expression changes them to:

```
MY_BASE_DIR=${MY_BASE_DIR-/usr/local}
```

The effect is that `/usr/local` is not used as a fixed value, but only as the *default value*. You can override it by setting the environment variable `MY_BASE_DIR`.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, I would take a look at the ExplainShell website:

[http://explainshell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sed%20-i%20%27s%2FMY_BASE_DIR%3D%5C%28.*%5C%29%2FMY_BASE_DIR%3D%24%7BMY_BASE_DIR-%5C1%7D%2F%27%20*.sh)

that will give you a breakdown of the command structure etc. In this instance, let step through the details...Let's start with a simple example, let's assume that we were going to make the simple change - commenting out all lines by adding a "#" before each line. We can do this for all `*.sh` files in a directory with the ".sh" extension in the current directory:

```
sed 's/^/\#/' *.sh
```

### i.e. Substitute beginning of line `^`, with a `#` ...

Caveat: You did not specify the OS you are using. You may get different results with different versions of sed and OS...

ok, now we can drill into the substitution in the script. An example is probably easier to explain:

```
File: t.sh
MY_BASE_DIR="/important data/data/bin"
```

the command `'s/MY_BASE_DIR=\(.*\)/MY_BASE_DIR=${MY_BASE_DIR-\1}/' *.sh`

will search for `"MY_BASE_DIR"` in each .sh file in the directory.

When it encounters the string `"MY_BASE_DIR=.*"`, in the file, it expands it to be `MY_BASE_DIR="/important data/data/bin"`, this is now replaced on the right side of the expression `/MY_BASE_DIR=${MY_BASE_DIR-\1}/` which becomes

```
MY_BASE_DIR=${MY_BASE_DIR-"/important data/data/bin"}
```

essentially what happens is that the substitute operation takes

***MY_BASE_DIR="/important data/data/bin"***

and inserts

MY_BASE_DIR=**${MY_BASE_DIR-**"/important data/data/bin"**}**

now if we run the script with the variable MY_BASE_DIR set

export MY_BASE_DIR="/new/import/dir"

the scripts modified by the sed script referenced will now substitute **/important data/data/bin** with **/new/import/dir**...